# .htaccess wordpress - rewrite subdomains to main domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a wordpress site with the wordpress files in a different folder (wpaw)

```
Wordpress url https://example.com/wapw
Site url https://example.com
```

I also have 3 or 4 subdomains, for example `new.example.com`

Currently the main domain and all the subdomains work correctly with the following `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wpaw/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wpaw/$1
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /wpaw/index.php  [L]
```

How can I modify the above so that http(s)://anysubdomain.example.com also redirects to https://example.com

Answer (score 0):

Please write the below code in **.htaccess** file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^anysubdomain\.example\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https:/.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Comment: adding just  this will break my wordpress site - it needs to be in addition to the existing `RewriteRules`

Comment: @MichaelT yes you need to add in existing RewriteRules.